# Blackberry Custom ButtonField with no Border

Tags: blackberry, buttonfield

how could i create a custom ButtonField with no border in Blackberry...
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bingo, just add the applyTheme() method

```
class BitmapButtonField extends ButtonField {

        protected void applyTheme()
        {

        }        
}
```

Arhimed & Rafael,  thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2):

Use [this tutorial](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Create_a_custom_field_508117_11.jsp) to create your own custom field.

Control the appearance of your field in paint() method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible by extending `Field`. You just need to create 2 images (one for a focused state and one for an unfocused state). Just don't draw the border on those images.

A sample implementation can be found [here](http://swati-blackberry.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-create-custom-button-field-in.html).

Answer (score 1):

As Arhimed said, you should extend `Field`. This will give you the maximum amount of customization over how the button looks.

Here's an example of a customizable button I've created: https://github.com/HeshamMegid/BlackBerry-Custom-Controls

You could use it as it is or modify the code further to suit your needs.